# What is the role of `Base` class used in the built-in module `unittest.mock`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaprogramming, python-unittest.mock

While having deep dive into how the built-in `unittest.mock` was designed, I run into [these lines](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.12/Lib/unittest/mock.py#L401C1-L409C29) in the official source code of `mock.py`:

```py
class Base(object):
    _mock_return_value = DEFAULT
    _mock_side_effect = None
    def __init__(self, /, *args, **kwargs):
        pass



class NonCallableMock(Base):
    ...
    # and later in the init
    def _init__ (...):
        ...
        _safe_super(NonCallableMock, self).__init__(
            spec, wraps, name, spec_set, parent,
            _spec_state
        )
```

What is the role of `Base` class besides providing common class attributes `_mock_return_value` and `_mock_side_effect` as it has just an empty `__init__` ?

And why `NonCallableMock` has to call `_safe_super(NonCallableMock, self).__init__()`, which I believe is exactly just the empty `__init__` method of the `Base` class ?

Thanks a lot for your answers in advance.

I tried to understand the code but couldn't see the rationale behind the design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's for multiple inheritance, which `unittest.mock` uses for classes like `class MagicMock(MagicMixin, Mock):`.

Despite the name, `super` doesn't mean "call the superclass method". Instead, it finds the next method implementation in a type's method resolution order, which might not come from a parent of the current class when multiple inheritance is involved. When you don't know what method `super` will call, you have to be a lot more careful about what arguments you pass to that method.

Most of the classes in this class hierarchy forward arguments like `spec` and `wraps` to the next `__init__` implementation when they call `_safe_super(...).__init__(...)`. Even if none of their ancestors need those arguments, a sibling implementation could still need them. If *all* of the classes were to forward these arguments, then `object.__init__` would eventually receive those arguments, and `object.__init__` would throw an exception.

Some class has to handle the job of specifically *not* passing those arguments to `object.__init__`, and that class has to sit at the root of the class hierarchy, right below `object` itself.

Thus, this `Base` class: a class for all the other classes in this multiple inheritance hierarchy to inherit from, existing almost solely for the purpose of preventing `object.__init__` from complaining.

Comment: Got it! thanks a lot for your clear answer.